# How do I install a clean WIN 7 ULT on my DELL VOSTRO 1014?

Tags: windows-7, windows-installation, dell-vostro

I've an old Dell Vostro 1014 (mid 2009). As I tried installing OS WIN 7 64 bit ULTIMATE through CD/DVD RW, I pressed and checked all the function keys one at a time but all in vain. The system would ask me to 'repair the computer', or at other time the blue screen will show up and go all black at the blink of an eye. How do I overcome this? Can the OS installation be done using external drive like pendrive? Please help me out. Also give me the link to download the require drivers of this laptop. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the required drivers by going to support.dell.com, entering your Service Tag, and then selecting Windows 7. It will then list all the Dell drivers and utilities for Windows 7 that you can download.

If you are trying to install from a DVD, you should try to get into the BIOS (usually by pressing DEL, ESC, TAB, F1, F2, F10 or F11 right after turning on the computer) and make sure the boot order is set so you can boot from the optical drive. The optical drive should be listed before the hard drive.

Comment: I've gone through BIOS, set the boot order to CD/DVD RW. Now this is the display: 
" No bootable devices--strike F1 to retry boot, F2 for setup utility
  Press F5 to run onboard diagnostics. "
Is my optical drive damaged? The OS installation DVD disc works fine when I test with other laptop of mine.

Comment: If you think the optical drive is bad, you can get a small external usb dvd drive for $20-30 and try booting from that.